# Higher order function question involving closure

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

In chapter 5 of Eloquent Javascript (https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) there is an example that I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around.

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

I get the initial call of the function and assigning `n` to 10. It's when it's called a second time I don't understand how `11` would get passed to the variable `m` (wouldn't the parameter still be `n`? I almost want to think it would overwrite `10` with `11`).

When I do `alert(greaterThan10)` it shows `m => m > n` which I was also confused as to why it wouldn't show `n` as `10`.

Comment: That `return m => m > n` is (more or less) equal to `return function(m) { return m > n; }`

Comment: `greaterThan` returns a function (`m => m > n`). `greaterThan10` is said function; a function that takes one parameter `m`.

Comment: The closure doesn't replace the function body, it just saves the scope where `n == 10`. Use `console.dir(greaterThan10)` and look in the `[[Scopes]]` property to see this.

Comment: thanks, I think the arrow function was throwing me off